# Sending settings frame using ResponseWriter in golang

Tags: go, http2

I want to update the HTTP2 settings for an HTTP2 server connection, eg. Change the number of concurrent streams.

```
server := http2.Server{}

l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:1010")
checkErr(err, "while listening")

fmt.Printf("Listening [0.0.0.0:1010]...\n")
for {
conn, err := l.Accept()
checkErr(err, "during accept")

server.ServeConn(conn, &http2.ServeConnOpts{
    Handler: http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %v, http: %v", r.URL.Path, r.TLS == nil)
    }),
})
```

}

With just the Server and the ResponseWriter is it possible to update the HTTP2 settings by sending a SettingsFrame?